# Querying in sub-collections?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

This is my structure:
[image]
[image]

I want to query and display all the groups a specific user is present in.

I am querying the user like this:

```js
 componentDidMount() {
    const uid = auth().currentUser.uid;
    firestore()
      .collectionGroup('Members')
      .where('uid', '==', `${uid}`)
      .get()
      .then(doc => {
        doc.forEach(snap => {
          console.log(snap.id); // Gives User Document under Members sub-collection
        });
      });
  }
```

**But how do I retrive the groupdId of the document(from 'Groups' parent collection) that the user is present in??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `snap` is a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) type object, which contains a reference to the full path to the document queried in its [ref](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.html#ref) property.  You can use this [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.html) object to find out the parent collections and documents by walking up the path using its [parent](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.html#parent) property, or by parsing its [path](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.html#path) string.

```js
// a CollectionReference to Groups/{groupId}/Members
snap.ref.parent

// a DocumentReference to Groups/{groupId}
snap.ref.parent.parent  

// the string ID of the above DocumentReference {groupId}
snap.ref.parent.parent.id
```